# Co-Prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If two integers $a$ and $b$ are co-prime, how can I show that $a$ and $b^n$ are co-prime? I am guessing that first i must show a base case and then use induction but I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need induction. Do it by contradiction, if $a$ and $b^n$ are not coprime to each other, then there exists a non-trivial divisor $d$ of $a$ which divides $b^n$, let $p$ be a prime number dividing $d$. Justify that $p$ divides  $b$ which implies that $p$ is common divisor to both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

By contrapositive: If $a$ and $b^n$ are not coprime, they have a common non-trivial divisor, hence a common prime divisor $p$. Now, if $p$ divides  $b^n$, it divides $b$, by *Euclid's lemma*, and $a$ and $b$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be $x^q * y^w * z ^e $... Where x,y,z are prime numbers. Then $b$ will have none of x,y,z as divisors . therefore when I raise $b^n$ I won't be still having any prime factor which is also a prime factor is $a$.
Another way to understand is take $b$ as $f^i*g^o*h^p$..

Then because they are co prime none of  f,g,h.. will be equal to any of x,y,z.. So on raising b to $n$ you are raising it as $f^{in} * g^{on} * h^{pn}$. This it has the same factors. Making it again co prime. Note you can even say $a^n = b^n$